# iframe containing frameset document not expanding to full height of browser window

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, iframe, frameset

Have a problem that's been bugging me now for the past two days :(

I have set up an HTML web page that contains an **iFrame** that loads a **frameset document**. Yes I know, frames are ancient tech and should not be used, but that is the output produced from Adobe's RoboHelp tool so I need to deal with it.

I have attempted to add variations of JavaScript code that will resize the iFrame's height to fit the remaining height of the browser window. It works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc. , but like most organizations the client has standardized to ancient IE (Internet Explorer 8) and it does not look like they will move forward anytime soon.

An image of the current problem is conveyed here:

[image: the iframe does not occupy remaining space in IE 8]

Simply put, I cannot get the iFrame to occupy the space remaining between the banner and the footer in *Internet Explorer* (8). I have used both CSS styling and variations of JavaScript code to "read" (I guess) the height of the "frameset(?)" document in order to pass the height to the innerframe for resizing it. Most of the scripts I have seen rely on the height of the document inside the iFrame, but what happens when you have a frameset?

Here is the code of the main page containing the iFrame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>
body {
width:100%;
height:100%
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function autoHeight(e)
{
    alert(e);
    if ( e.contentDocument ) {

        e.height = e.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight + 35;
    }
    else {
        e.height = e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 35;
        alert("e.contentWindow = "+ e.contentWindow);
    }
}



this.onload = function(e) {
// or add it to the onload attribute of the body tag...
var ifr = document.getElementById('helpFrame');
    autoHeight(ifr);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--banner code here, not too important -->
<iframe frameborder="0" id="helpFrame" align="bottom" src="/RCMP/prod/index.htm" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" style="height:100%;">
    Your browser does not support iframes.
</iframe>
<!-- added some paragraphs to actually "push" the footer down for now. -->
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--footer code here-->
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the frameset (contained in the iFrame, from Adobe's RoboHelp published output). A lot of the javascript can be ignored, I believe the focus is on the frameset)

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <title>Orientation Guide To E-Division Headquarters</title>

 <meta name="generator" content="Adobe RoboHelp 9" />
 <meta name="description" content="WebHelp 5.50" />

</head>


<frameset cols="100%,*" frameborder=no border=0>
  <frame src="whnjs.htm">
  <frame src="whskin_blank.htm" noresize>
</frameset><noframes></noframes>

</html>
```

So the challenge is to get that iFrame to go full height (down to the footer) in IE! Any suggestions / solutions would be appreciated. I don't really want to use jQuery if I don't have to - JavaScript and CSS would be nice.

thanks!